# Can I have more than 1 upload key concurrently in Google Play Console?

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle, google-play-console, android-app-signing

I have had an app A in Play store currently. I used an upload key A1 to sign the app A. And I am planning to upload an app B to play store but I would like to use another signing key that is different from the signing key for app A (the upload key B1). Then I get this warning from play console like this when upload app B with different key

[image]

For this reason, I have a question that can I have more than one upload key concurrently in Console. For example each app will have a individual key. Thanks